# Retrieving Record type values in dynamic for

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I've got function in which I use FOR loop with dynamic queries. Don't know why but postgres cannot retrieve single fields from record variable... Still got the error

`SELECT (1,token).id - syntax error`?

Is there any chance to get field value from this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mobile666(v_limit integer, v_offset integer) RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
  DECLARE
    r record;
    x text[];
    kap text;
    i_attrs text[] := ARRAY[
    ['test','id','value'],
    ['test', 'id','value'],
    ['test', 'id','value'],
    ['test', 'id','value']
    ];
    quer text;

  BEGIN
    FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY i_attrs LOOP
   FOR r in EXECUTE
    'SELECT * FROM ' || x[1]::regclass || ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(x[2]) || ' IS NOT NULL'  LOOP

  execute 'SELECT '|| r || '.' || quote_ident(x[2]) INTO kap;
     RAISE NOTICE 'id %', kap;
execute 'SELECT '|| r || '.' || quote_ident(x[5]) INTO kap;
     RAISE NOTICE 'id %', kap;

  END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

    END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 400;



CREATE TABLE test
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  value text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_test PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);


INSERT INTO test(
            id, value)
    VALUES (1,'token'),(2,'smt'),(3,'cocc');
```

Comment: Please always show your PostgreSQL version and the *full*, *exact* text of the error. You may find this code easier to understand if you  rewrite it to use `EXECUTE ... USING` with the `format` function's `%I` (identifier) format-specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mobile666(v_limit integer, v_offset integer) RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r record;
    x text[];
    kap text;
    i_attrs text[] := ARRAY[
    ['test','id','value'],
    ['test', 'id','value'],
    ['test', 'id','value'],
    ['test', 'id','value']
    ];
    quer text;

BEGIN
    FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY i_attrs LOOP
        FOR r in EXECUTE
            'SELECT * FROM ' || x[1]::regclass || ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(x[2]) || ' IS NOT NULL'  LOOP

            execute 'SELECT ($1::text::' || x[1] || ').' || x[2] INTO kap USING r;
            RAISE NOTICE 'id %', kap;
            execute 'SELECT ($1::text::' || x[1] || ').' || x[3] INTO kap USING r;
            RAISE NOTICE 'id %', kap;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 400;
```

The clue is to cast record `r` (`$1`) inside dynamic sql string to appropriate table  (`$1::text::table_name`). After this you have access to record columns like `($1::text::table_name).col_name` and you can change table name or column name dynamically.